# Hadoop single node cluster memory and storage requirements

Tags: vmware-esxi, hadoop

I have been advised to learn Hadoop for my company and so I want to build a test environment.

The company I work for has a datacentre with a VMware vCloud infrastructure which they use to sell private clouds to other companies.

I'm allowed to use some CPU, RAM, network and storage, but I can't seem to find a base level requirements for Hadoop in a small testing environment.

I am thinking to spin up a single VM working as a single node cluster, working on simple job like analysing 1000s of PDF documents for keywords, extracting paragraphs and reformatting into a single HTML document.

Can anyone advise on the minimum requirements I should provision for this VM, or where I can find this information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to learn how Hadoop works, I would recommend grabbing one of the available distributions on a VM.  These are designed to be small learning environments that get you running with a pseudo-distributed cluster running inside one node.

1. [Cloudera Quickstart VM](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/DemoVMs/Cloudera-QuickStart-VM/cloudera_quickstart_vm.html)
2. [Hortonworks Sandbox](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/)
3. [MapR Virtual Machine](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Installing+the+MapR+Virtual+Machine)

There may be others; these are just the ones I can think of off the top of my head.

If you're looking to build your own VM, the answer is:  it depends.

You would probably be fine starting out with 8-16GB of RAM, a few hundred gigabytes of disk space, and 2-4 cpu cores.  This would be sufficient to get you working in a pseudo-distributed configuration.

If you're talking about building a small cluster, you probably want 4 nodes:  1 namenode (2-4G memory, 1-2 CPUs), 3 datanodes (4-8GB of memory, as much space as you want/need).  This would be sufficient to get you a running HDFS and Mapreduce environment AND give you experience on setting up and running the cluster.  If you go this route, you will probably want to check out [Cloudera Manager](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products/cloudera-manager.html) or [Ambari with Hortonworks](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop/ambari/).

EDIT:

I almost forgot:  [vmware Serengeti](http://www.vmware.com/hadoop/serengeti.html) may be of interest to you since you're in a VMware infrastructure.